# Is there an equivalent to "Open Update"

Tags: streams

I'm writing a binary file that contains a header followed by the data.
The header contains the length of the data.

The data is written first, skipping past the header.
Once done, I would like to update the data length in the header (something easily done in C). *Mathematica* won't let me use `SetStreamPosition` as the stream is opened for output.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this impossible since I think I heard a developer complain about it in one of WRI's live streams, but is definitely something the language _should_ support